# Launch video from web page

Tags: http, video, web, h.264

I am trying to serve video files from my home web-server to my Kindle.  I have no interest in streaming the video outside of my LAN.  I can hit the web page and browse to the test video which is a MP4 of the movie LUCY (which I purchased) but the video will no play.  The same thing occurs with when using a PC.

I made certain to install the h.264 module in Apache.

Obviously I am working towards a personal "Netflix" site for home.

Any tips or advice will be warmly accepted!

Comment: Look up Plex. Its what you need.

Comment: Thank you but I was hoping to build something of my own.  :D